# how to disable user account php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to have user accounts that can be enabled or disabled.

I have a active field in my table that is set to either yes or no.

This is my code for the login page.

```
<?php
/* User login process, checks if user exists and password is correct */

require_once 'includes/db.php';

// Escape email to protect against SQL injections
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dxd_membership WHERE email='$email'");
if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ){ // User doesn't exist
$_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
header("location: error.php");
}
else { // User exists
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
$active = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dxd_membership WHERE email = '$email' AND active = 'YES'");

if ($active == '1')
{
    if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) ) {
        $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $user['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $user['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
        $_SESSION['paynum'] = $user['paynum'];
        $_SESSION['empnum'] = $user['empnum'];
        $_SESSION['phone'] = $user['phone'];
        $_SESSION['active'] = $user['active'];
        $_SESSION['lastlogin'] = $user['lastlogin'];
        $_SESSION['signup'] = $user['signup'];
        $_SESSION['lastupdate'] = $user['lastupdate'];

        // This is how we'll know the user is logged in
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

        $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE dxd_membership SET lastlogin=NOW() WHERE email = '$email'");

        header("location: welcome.php");
    }

    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You have entered wrong password please try again!";
        header("location: error.php");
    }
}

else {
    header("location: disabled.php");
}
}
?>
```

I am sure it is a silly error i have here but it will not check the active field and then either let the user login to the welcome.php page if active is yes or send them to the disabled.php page if their account active is set to no (disabled).

Can anyone help me with correcting the code so that it will work.

Thanks

Comment: Why `$active == '1'`, if you get a return you know the active is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, I see several issues in your code. The first is the double query for the same data. You can simplify this whole thing to **one** query.

<s>Another (and more important) is the fact that you're just appending data to the SQL query, where the whole objective of MySQLi is to avoid injections by binding params. So a -more- correct way to do it would be this one:</s>

**EDIT:** `escape_string` avoids this. I completely ignored it.

```
<?php
    /* User login process, checks if user exists and password is correct */

    require_once 'includes/db.php';

    // Escape email to protect against SQL injections
    $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dxd_membership WHERE email = '{$email}'");
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ){ // User doesn't exist
        $_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
        header("Location: error.php");
        exit; // Add an "exit" here, because if you add something else, it will run too (even if you asked to redirect... basically is the browser the one that chooses if it follows the redirect or not, but your script still goes on).
    }
    else { // User exists
        $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

        // There's no point in filtering using another MySQL query, since YOU ALREADY HAVE THIS DATA. Just use PHP to read it and act appropiately.
        // Doing another query is just WASTING resources for no useful purpose.
        //$active = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dxd_membership WHERE email = '$email' AND active = 'YES'");
        if ( $user['active'] == 'YES' ) {
            // Your processing here, you get the idea
        }
    }
?>
```

Of course, the best alternative is to use a MySQLi statement and use `bind_param`/`execute`. This example is only to follow your style of using MySQLi.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious

```
$active = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dxd_membership WHERE email = '$email' AND    active = 'YES'");

if ($active == '1') //<-- see it
{
   if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) )
```

Try this

```
if ($active->num_rows == 1 ) //or != 0 This is false or a result set.
```

Even if you did have the value of their active filed in there ( you have select `*` ) you would still be checking string `'1'` against string `'YES'`

Please **note** I haven't used mysqli in about 4 years, as I use PDO.  So that might not be the entire problem, but just seemed wrong..

In fact that second query is not needed as you already have the data you seek, so you can change it.

Now if you are sure active will always be `YES` for them being active, the `$user` already contains this data, so why not use it like this, and save the query.

```
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dxd_membership WHERE email='$email'");
if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ){ // User doesn't exist
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";
    header("location: error.php");
}else { // User exists
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    /*  comment these next 2 lines out when not debugging */
    echo "<pre>"; //whitespace formating
    var_export( $user );

    if ($user['active'] == 'YES'){
    // .....



    }
}
```

One thing I feel compelled to mention is that you should look into prepared statements.  You can find information on that here

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Whenever you concatenate in a SQL query you should be using a prepared statement instead, as it opens you application to SQL injection attacks. Now that I look closer you are using `escape_string` while this is good, the preferred way is prepared statements. This is because with a prepared statement, the variables are entirely separate from the query commands and so the DB knows not to execute anything in them.  Even with escaping there could be edge cases that may be an issue, I don't know of any per-say, but something like using a Hexadecimal version of a quote are things I have seen in examples, or weird character strings that the DB would see as a quote.

Comment: `$active` could be `1`, but that's a query resource, isn't it? I would say `if ($active->num_rows == 1)` is more correct.

Comment: @AlejandroIván - see my update, it may be evaluated as `1`, only because it's not false.

Comment: so the 1 should be yes ?? sorry if stupid question but i new as you can no doubt tell so am still learning

Comment: Yeah, I just said "more correct" because, as a resource, I believe `$active` is a pointer, so it could be any number different than `0`. The only case I can think of a query returning 0 is a bad connection.

Comment: Ok sorry for being stupid and new but the num_rows has solved it - thankyou very much for all the help ;)

Comment: @Boxecutor - give me a second, the query for that is unnecessary

Comment: see you have already selected the row using `*` when checking their password, so there is no need to do a second query for that information, you can simply check the `$user` array you already have.